# Testing a Content model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm new to RSpec and testing in general. I've come up with a spec for testing my `Content` model and I need some feedback because I think there are many improvements that can be done. I don't know if the way I did it is considered over-testing, bloated/wrong code or something. This test is kinda slow but this doesn't bother me that much for now.

**app/models/content.rb**

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [ :slugged, :history ]
  acts_as_mediumable

  delegate :title, to: :category, prefix: true

  # Associations
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :slides, dependent: :destroy

  # Accessible attributes
  attr_accessible :title, :summary, :body, :category_id,
                  :seo_description, :seo_keywords, :seo_title,
                  :unpublished_at, :published_at, :is_draft

  # Validations
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :category, presence: true
  validates :published_at, timeliness: { allow_nil: false, allow_blank: false }
  validates :unpublished_at, timeliness: { allow_nil: true, allow_blank: true, after: :published_at }, :if => "published_at.present?"

  scope :published, lambda { |*args|
    now = ( args.first || Time.zone.now )
    where(is_draft: false).
    where("(published_at <= ? AND unpublished_at IS NULL) OR (published_at <= ? AND ? <= unpublished_at)", now, now, now).
    order("published_at DESC")
  }

  def self.blog_posts
    joins(:category).where(categories: { acts_as_blog: true })
  end

  def self.latest_post
    blog_posts.published.first
  end

  def to_s
    title
  end

  def seo
    meta = Struct.new(:title, :keywords, :description).new
    meta.title = seo_title.presence || title.presence
    meta.description = seo_description.presence || summary.presence
    meta
  end

end
```

**spec/models/content_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Content do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    create(:content).should be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid without a title" do
    build(:content, title: nil).should_not be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid without a body" do
    build(:content, body: nil).should_not be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid without a category" do
    build(:content, category: nil).should_not be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid when publication date is nil" do
    build(:content, published_at: nil).should_not be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid when publication date is blank" do
    build(:content, published_at: "").should_not be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid when publication date is malformed" do
    build(:content, published_at: "!0$2-as-#{nil}").should_not be_valid
  end

  # TODO: You shall not pass! (for now)
  # it "is invalid when expiration date is malformed" do
  #   build(:content, unpublished_at: "!0$2-as-#{nil}").should_not be_valid
  # end

  it "is invalid when publication date is nil and expiration date is set" do
    build(:content, published_at: nil, unpublished_at: 3.weeks.ago).should_not be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid when expiration date is before publication date" do
    build(:content, published_at: 1.week.ago, unpublished_at: 2.weeks.ago).should_not be_valid
  end

  it "returns a content's title as a string" do
    content = create(:content)
    content.to_s.should eq content.title
  end

  describe "filters by publication dates" do
    before :each do
      @published_three_weeks_ago = create(:published_three_weeks_ago_content)
      @expiring_in_two_weeks = create(:expiring_in_two_weeks_content)
      @publish_in_tree_weeks = create(:publish_in_tree_weeks_content)
    end

    context "with matching dates" do
      it "returns a sorted array of results that match for current time" do
        Content.published.should include @published_three_weeks_ago, @expiring_in_two_weeks
      end

      it "returns a sorted array of results that match for future time" do
        Content.published(3.weeks.from_now).should include @published_three_weeks_ago, @publish_in_tree_weeks
      end
    end

    context "without matching dates" do
      it "returns an empty array" do
        Content.published(2.months.ago).should eq [ ]
      end
    end
  end

  describe "filters contents by blog category" do
    before :each do
      @blog_category = create(:blog_category)
    end

    context "with matching contents" do
      it "returns only blog posts" do
        one_page = create(:content)
        another_page = create(:content)
        first_post = create(:content, category: @blog_category)
        second_post = create(:content, category: @blog_category)

        Content.blog_posts.should include first_post, second_post
      end
    end

    context "without matching contents" do
      it "returns an empty array" do
        one_page = create(:content)
        another_page = create(:content)

        Content.blog_posts.should eq [ ]
      end
    end
  end

  describe "retrieves latest post" do
    before :each do
      @blog_category = create(:blog_category)
    end

    context "with existing posts" do
      it "return the latest content that belongs to a blog category" do
        first_post = create(:published_three_weeks_ago_content, category: @blog_category)
        second_post = create(:content, published_at: Time.zone.now, category: @blog_category)

        Content.latest_post.should eq second_post
      end
    end

    context "without existing posts" do
      it "returns an nil object" do
        Content.latest_post.should eq nil
      end
    end
  end

  describe "uses seo attributes when present" do
    before :each do
      @it = create(:content)
    end

    context "seo title present" do
      it "returns seo title when present" do
        @it.seo.title.should eq @it.seo_title
      end
    end

    context "seo title non present" do
      it "returns title when seo title is blank" do
        @it.seo_title = ""
        @it.seo.title.should eq @it.title
      end

      it "returns title when seo title is nil" do
        @it.seo_title = nil
        @it.seo.title.should eq @it.title
      end
    end

    context "seo description present" do
      it "returns seo description when present" do
        @it.seo.description.should eq @it.seo_description
      end
    end

    context "seo description non present" do
      it "returns description when seo description is blank" do
        @it.seo_description = ""
        @it.seo.description.should eq @it.summary
      end

      it "returns description when seo description is nil" do
        @it.seo_description = nil
        @it.seo.description.should eq @it.summary
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/contents.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :content do
    association :category
    title { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    summary { Faker::Lorem.sentence(10) }
    body { Faker::Lorem.sentence(15) }
    seo_title { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    seo_description { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    seo_keywords { Faker::Lorem.words(8).join(", ") }
    published_at { Time.zone.now }
    is_draft { false }

    factory :published_three_weeks_ago_content do
      published_at { 3.weeks.ago }
    end

    factory :expiring_in_two_weeks_content do
      unpublished_at { 2.weeks.from_now }
    end

    factory :publish_in_tree_weeks_content do
      published_at { 3.weeks.from_now }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that David Chelimsky advises against the use of an explicit subject: http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice job.  Your tests are nicely compartmentalized.  It is indeed good to test the factory independently.  Good use of *describe* and *context*.

**Consider using the shoulda-matchers gem**

Tests for many of the rails model associations and validations can be handled by the [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem.  For example, this line:

```
validates :title, presence: true
```

can be tested like so:

```
it {should validate_presence_of(:title)}
```

**Consider using [*pending*](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/pending/pending-examples)**

Here's a commented-out test:

```
# TODO: You shall not pass! (for now)
# it "is invalid when expiration date is malformed" do
#   build(:content, unpublished_at: "!0$2-as-#{nil}").should_not be_valid
# end
```

Rspec has a method for documenting tests that don't (and can't yet be made to) pass:

```
it "is invalid when expiration date is malformed" do
  pending
  build(:content, unpublished_at: "!0$2-as-#{nil}").should_not be_valid
end
```

The nice thing about *pending* is that it shows up in the test output, making it less easily forgotten than commented-out code.  Also, you can give a reason, e.g.:

```
pending "Can't pass until the vendor fixes library xyz"
```

**For clarity, Consider redoing things the factory did**

This test:

```
context "seo description present" do
  it "returns seo description when present" do
    @it.seo.description.should eq @it.seo_description
  end
end
```

Relies upon the factory having having set the description, but the factory is a long way from the test.  This would be clearer if explicit:

```
context "seo description present" do
  it "returns seo description when present" do
    @it.seo_description = 'foo bar baz'
    @it.seo.description.should eq @it.seo_description
  end
end
```

**Consider using *subject***

Some of your test sets a variable in a `before` block and later tests that variable:

before :each do
      @it = create(:content)
    end

```
context "seo title present" do
  it "returns seo title when present" do
    @it.seo.title.should eq @it.seo_title
  end
end
```

Instead of assigning to a variable, rspec lets you [declare a subject](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Subject/ExampleGroupMethods#subject-instance_method):

```
subject {create(:content)}
```

Once you've declared a subject, some snazzy syntax becomes available to you:

```
its('seo.title') {should == subject.title}
```

`subject.seo_title` is [a little awkward](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/), so rspec lets you name your subject:

```
subject(:content) {create(:content)}
its('seo.title') {should == content.title}
```

**Consider using *let* along with *subject***

In rspec, *let* defines a memoized, lazily-evaluated value.  When used with `subject`, this can [DRY up a spec](http://benscheirman.com/2011/05/dry-up-your-rspec-files-with-subject-let-blocks):

```
describe "seo.title" do

  let(:title) {'title'}
  subject {create :content, :title => title, :seo_title => seo_title}

  context 'seo title present' do
    let(:seo_title) {'seo title'}
    its('seo.title') {should eq seo_title}
  end

  context 'seo title missing' do
    let(:seo_title) {nil}
    its('seo.title') {should eq title}
  end

end
```

Comment: Hey Wayne thanks for the reply. You pointed out some really useful stuff. The let/subject/its seems useful, so I'll have to take a look at the documentation. Cheers ;)

Comment: One more to get this right. When using `subject` here: `subject {create :content, :title => title, :seo_title => seo_title}`, does the `seo_title` gets evaluated when `let(:seo_title) {'seo title'}` is executed later on? Normally it would raise an error for using an undefined variable... 

Also here: `its('seo.title') {should eq title}` is `title` referring to `subject.title` or to the variable `title` set in the beggining, cause every time I tried something like this `its('seo.title') {should eq subject.title}` just got that `subject` is a string.

Comment: @gtz, Instead of `its('seo.title') {should eq subject.title}` try `specify {subject.seo.title.should eq subject.title}`.  There are... quirks... with _its_ ability to evaluate an arbitrary string.

Comment: I see. I'm just starting to discover the ways of RSpec. Thanks a lot for the tips!